# Resin printer build plate scratches/ damage

Tags: build-plate, resin, build-surface

I have an anycubic photon, and occasionally have trouble removing prints from the build plate. While trying to removing prints I've put some scratches into the surface, as I guess I've come in at the wrong angle trying to get under and leverage the print.
Typical examples I've seen of people removing prints, they appear to come at it hard with a blunt edge. I've come across scrapers that are blunt and some with a sharper edges.

I've put a bit more a ding into my plate today, using a scraper with more of a blade edge for a difficult to remove print. I had used the same scrapper before with great success, as it slide right under and I could leverage the print, but struggled with it today and scratched up my plate.
I haven't come across much discussion on this so thought I'd ask about scratches to the build plates.

Are scratches to the build plate something to be concerned about, is it something that it expected when removing prints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One of the resources](https://forum.formlabs.com/t/scrapes-on-build-platform/17203/12) I've found is a forum with a discussion of the impact of scratches.

The general consensus is that scratches are not a problem, as long as there are no burrs above the surface of the plate that would damage the bottom of the vat. One posting party has used 36 grit on a palm sander followed by scotchbrite pad to resurface his plate, but one takes the risk of creating an out-of-plane surface.

A better method to sand a plate would be to place the sandpaper on a glass surface or something equally flat and planar and pass the build plate repeatedly over that.

Another aspect of the discussion was that scratches are good, as the rough surface provides a better bond to the resin.

You're likely to note that your build plate is not a polished smooth surface for the same reason.